# Multithreading in a monad

Tags: multithreading, haskell, concurrency

I need to run multiple concurrent processes in a context of the same monad, say, `Connection`. I expected something like the following would work:

```
main = runConnection connectionSettings $ do
  forkIO action1
  forkIO action2
  action3
```

but `forkIO` required to be run in an `IO` context and actions to be in `IO` too.

Assuming those actions have a type `:: Connection ()`, what needs to be done to run them concurrently (which instances to implement and etc)?

Currently I'm working around this as follows, but evidently this ain't right:

```
main = do
  forkIO $ runConnection connectionSettings action1
  forkIO $ runConnection connectionSettings action2
  runConnection connectionSettings action3
```

Comment: There's absolutely no guarantee that it even _can_ be done at all in a meaningful way. For anyone to say anything for sure, though, you'll need to say what `Connection` is.

Comment: Have you looked at monad-parallel? http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-parallel/0.7.1.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-Parallel.html

Comment: @ItaiZukerman Thank you! This seems very promising

Comment: @DanielWagner It's just a made up example. One of monads I'm actually having troubles with is a custom wrapper over [HTTP Conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/http-conduit/1.8.6.1/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v:withManager) and a `StateT`, which keeps the state of a session. And it seems to make sense for actions to share session.

Comment: It's not possible to (meaningfully) fork inside a `StateT s`. However, you can meaningfully fork inside a `ReaderT (MVar s)`...

Comment: @DanielWagner Why not `StateT (MVar s)`, or, at least, a `ReaderT` + `WriterT` over `MVar`? I need to be able to change the value.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov An `MVar` is already mutable. You don't need to change the reference -- only the value it's referencing!

Answer (score 3):

I've found a beautiful ["monad-parallel"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-parallel)  library intended for very similar purposes, and an even more powerful fork of it - ["classy-parallel"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/classy-parallel).

For a monad to be usable in a parallelizable manner it needs to have an instance of a [`Parallel`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/classy-parallel/0.1.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Parallel.html#t%3aParallel) typeclass. And the "classy-parallel" library already provides instances for the most important types for such purposes: `ResourceT IO` and `ReaderT`.

Assuming the presence of appropriate instances the code in question can be transformed to following:

```
import qualified Control.Monad.Parallel as Parallel

main = runConnection connectionSettings $ 
  Parallel.sequence [action1, action2, action3]
```

For simply forking in `ResourceT` the [`resourceForkIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/resourcet/0.3.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Resource.html#v%3aresourceForkIO) can be useful. There's also a ["monad-fork"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-fork-0.1) library which provides a neat and simple generalization over forking on top of `forkIO` and `resourceForkIO`.